# Mounting a volume for AWS Batch

Tags: aws-batch

We have some AWS batch processes that run nicely, using images from ECS. We do not assign any volumes or storage, and it seems we get 8gb by default. I'm not actually sure why/where that is defined.

Anyway we now have a situation where we need more space. It's only temporary processing space - we need to extract an archive, convert it, re-compress it and then upload it to S3. We already have this process, it's just that we've now ran out of space in our 8gb allowance.

So; Just to be absolutely sure, how should we go about adding this space? I see a few things about connecting EFS to the instance, is that a good use case? Are there considerations regarding to multiple jobs running at the same time etc? (There are scenarios where this is allowed - since it's a generic unzipper process, that gets called many times).

So the requirement is a throwaway storage volume, that doesn't need to persist, it can disappear once the AWS batch job finishes. The data files that have currently blown it up are 9gb, i'm not sure how much our image itself uses. Alpine linux so presumably not a huge amount.

Or of course, if we can simply tune that initial 8gb up by a couple of gb then we're laughing...

Answer (score 1):

As of now, by default EC2 instances on Batch have 30 GB EBS storage attached. This can be tuned by adding a custom launch template as presented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/launch-templates.html):

```
    {
        "LaunchTemplateName": "increase-container-volume-encrypt",
        "LaunchTemplateData": {
            "BlockDeviceMappings": [
                {
                    "DeviceName": "/dev/xvda",
                    "Ebs": {
                        "Encrypted": true,
                        "VolumeSize": 100,
                        "VolumeType": "gp2"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Then, add it to the compute environment definition:

```
    {
        "computeEnvironmentName": "",
        "type": "MANAGED",
        "state": "ENABLED",
        "computeResources": {
            "type": "EC2",
            "allocationStrategy": "BEST_FIT_PROGRESSIVE",
            "minvCpus": 2,
            "maxvCpus": 20,
            "desiredvCpus": 2,
            "instanceTypes": [
                "c6i"
            ],
            "imageId": "",
            "subnets": [
                ""
            ],
            "launchTemplate": {
                "launchTemplateName": "increase-container-volume-encrypt"
            },
            ]
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Only info I'm finding is in specifying a custom Launch Template in the Environment definition, and the Launch Template setup is as follows: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/batch-mount-efs/