# How can I mount EFS to a Docker container volume using AWS Batch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, containers, mount, amazon-efs

I can't figure this out for life of me.

The documentation that I can find doesn't describe how to do this (a lot of "Hello World" through the dashboard). I'm running this through the command line interface.

I'm trying to figure out how to use AWS Batch to process some data.  To do that, I have containerized my workflow and pushed the Docker container to DockerHub.  Since the Docker container can only see files within the container, I've set up directories in the Docker container to mount volumes.  Each Docker container has the following directories: `/volumes/input/`, `/volumes/output/`, and `/volumes/database/`.  I copied the necessary files from S3 to EFS but I'm having trouble getting all the pieces to work together.

**In particular, I need help creating a job definition that does the following: 1) Pulls my Docker container from DockerHub; 2) Mounts the EFS file system to the container; 3) Specifies the local paths within the EFS to map to the volumes in my container.**

Here's my typical workflow on a local machine running Docker:

```
# Directories
LOCAL_WORKING_DIRECTORY=$(pwd)
LOCAL_WORKING_DIRECTORY=$(realpath -m ${LOCAL_WORKING_DIRECTORY})
LOCAL_OUTPUT_PARENT_DIRECTORY=../
LOCAL_OUTPUT_PARENT_DIRECTORY=$(realpath -m ${LOCAL_OUTPUT_PARENT_DIRECTORY})
LOCAL_DATABASE_DIRECTORY=${VEBA_DATABASE}
LOCAL_DATABASE_DIRECTORY=$(realpath -m ${LOCAL_DATABASE_DIRECTORY})

CONTAINER_INPUT_DIRECTORY=/volumes/input/
CONTAINER_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/volumes/output/
CONTAINER_DATABASE_DIRECTORY=/volumes/database/

# Parameters
ID=S1
R1=Fastq/${ID}_1.fastq.gz
R2=Fastq/${ID}_2.fastq.gz
NAME=VEBA-preprocess__${ID}
RELATIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=veba_output/preprocess/

# Command
CMD="preprocess.py -1 ${CONTAINER_INPUT_DIRECTORY}/${R1} -2 ${CONTAINER_INPUT_DIRECTORY}/${R2} -n ${ID} -p 16 -o ${CONTAINER_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}/${RELATIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY} -x ${CONTAINER_DATABASE_DIRECTORY}/Contamination/chm13v2.0/chm13v2.0"

# Docker
# Version
VERSION=1.2.0

# Image
DOCKER_IMAGE="jolespin/veba_preprocess:${VERSION}"

# Run
docker run \
    --name ${NAME} \
    --rm \
    --volume ${LOCAL_WORKING_DIRECTORY}:${CONTAINER_INPUT_DIRECTORY}:ro \
    --volume ${LOCAL_OUTPUT_PARENT_DIRECTORY}:${CONTAINER_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}:rw \
    --volume ${LOCAL_DATABASE_DIRECTORY}:${CONTAINER_DATABASE_DIRECTORY}:ro \
    ${DOCKER_IMAGE} \
    -c "${CMD}"
```

I'm trying to do this exact command using AWS Batch via Fargate but can't figure out the job definition.  Can someone please help me achieve this?

```
{
  "jobDefinitionName": "preprocess__35",
  "type": "container",
  "containerProperties": {
    "image": "docker.io/jolespin/veba_preprocess:1.2.0",
    "command": [
      "preprocess.py",
      "-1",
      "/volumes/input/35_R1.fq.gz",
      "-2",
      "/volumes/input/35_R2.fq.gz",
      "-n",
      "35",
      "-o",
      "/volumes/output/veba_output/preprocess",
      "-p",
      "16"
    ],
    "jobRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::xxx:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
    "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::xxx:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
    "volumes": [
      {
        "name": "efs-volume-input",
        "efsVolumeConfiguration": {
          "fileSystemId": "fs-xxx",
      "transitEncryption": "ENABLED",
          "rootDirectory": "/mnt/efs/Fastq/"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "efs-volume-output",
        "efsVolumeConfiguration": {
          "fileSystemId": "fs-xxx",
          "transitEncryption": "ENABLED",
          "rootDirectory": "/mnt/efs/veba_output"
        }
      }
    ],
    "mountPoints": [
      {
        "sourceVolume": "efs-volume-input",
        "containerPath": "/volumes/input",
        "readOnly": true
      },
      {
        "sourceVolume": "efs-volume-output",
        "containerPath": "/volumes/output",
        "readOnly": false
      }
    ],
    "environment": [],
    "ulimits": [],
    "resourceRequirements": [
      {
        "value": "16.0",
        "type": "VCPU"
      },
      {
        "value": "122880",
        "type": "MEMORY"
      }
    ],
    "networkConfiguration": {
      "assignPublicIp": "ENABLED"
    },
    "fargatePlatformConfiguration": {
      "platformVersion": "LATEST"
    },
    "ephemeralStorage": {
      "sizeInGiB": 40
    }
  },
  "tags": {
    "Name": "preprocess__35"
  },
  "platformCapabilities": [
    "FARGATE"
  ]
}
```

**How can I specify the mounted EFS paths to map to the volumes in the container?**

These don't address my problem:

[AWS Batch: mount an efs volume into a container using cloud formation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66373392/aws-batch-mount-an-efs-volume-into-a-container-using-cloud-formation)

[Mounting a volume for AWS Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62409029/mounting-a-volume-for-aws-batch)

**Here's the error I get (no log files):**

ResourceInitializationError: failed to invoke EFS utils commands to set up EFS volumes: stderr: b'mount.nfs4: mounting 127.0.0.1:/mnt/efs/Fastq/ failed, reason given by server: No such file or directory' : unsuccessful EFS utils command execution; code: 32

Comment: is your dockerhub image public or private ?

Comment: if we divide this tasks in small pieces, first...are you able to pull from docker hub to ECS (if image is not public )?

Comment: @jmvcollaborator I'm pretty sure it's public: https://hub.docker.com/layers/jolespin/veba_preprocess/1.2.0/images/sha256-bc7afd1134ef364e46962d791be42de9f3d26dd28de22db9066e0d70b5832a4b?context=explore

Comment: weird you needed to add docker.io/ that should not be required, do you know if its pulled correctly to ECS ?

Comment: @jmvcollaborator maybe I don't need add this.  If I just give it the tag for the container, will it know to look for docker hub instead of ECR?

Comment: this looks like the security group for EFS is not letting the inbound connection at port 2409

Answer (score 0):

resource: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/job_definition_parameters.html#containerProperties

1)
when you use a dockerhub public image just use the name of the image and place your job in a security group with an egress rule allowing access to the internet (0.0.0.0/0):

```
"container": {
    "image": "jolespin/veba_preprocess:1.2.0",
    ...
]
```

2 & 3)

When you want to use an EFS volume first step is to define the volume (s) using **volumes** property as you already did.

```
"volumes": [
  {
    "name": "efs-volume",
    "efsVolumeConfiguration": {
      "fileSystemId": "fs-xxxxxxxxxx",
      "rootDirectory": "/",
      "transitEncryption": "DISABLED"
    }
  },
 ...
]
```

In this configuration the **name** of the volume is **"efs-volume"** and is the name that we will use to attach the volume to the container. And the **rootDirectory** is the folder in the efs that the volume will use, in this case, the root **/**.

The second step is to define the **mountPoints** which is the property where you attach the previous volume to your container.

```
"mountPoints": [
  {
    "containerPath": "/internal/path1",
    "readOnly": false,
    "sourceVolume": "efs-volume"
  },
 ...
]
```

The above example mounts efs "/" in container "/internal/path1"

So, as the volumes property  is an array you can create as many volumes as you need with different rootDirectory's and bind them to the container using the mountPoints (with different containerPath's).

---

NOTE:

Networking configurations:

job secutity group must have an egress rule to efs security group in 2049 port (tcp)

job subnets must be the same where efs has the mount targets ...

Comment: waiting for IT to adjust the permissions so I haven't gotten a chance to thoroughly test but I awarded you the bounty so it didn't go to waste.  I'll update you in a few days once I'm able to test it out.

Comment: I'm getting the following error: 
`ResourceInitializationError: failed to invoke EFS utils commands to set up EFS volumes: stderr: b'mount.nfs4: mounting 127.0.0.1:/mnt/efs/Fastq/ failed, reason given by server: No such file or directory' : unsuccessful EFS utils command execution; code: 32. `

I tried specifying the input volumne like this: `"name": "efs-volume-input", "efsVolumeConfiguration": { "fileSystemId": "fs-xxxx", "transitEncryption": "ENABLED", "rootDirectory": "/mnt/efs/Fastq/" }`

Comment: and the mount point like this: `      {
        "sourceVolume": "efs-volume-input",
        "containerPath": "/volumes/input",
        "readOnly": true
      },`

Comment: /mnt/efs/Fastq/ alrady exist in efs ?

Comment: look at this link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/troubleshooting-efs-mounting.html#mount-error-no-such-file

Comment: Yea it already exists in EFS.  Im in the directory now.  Do I need specify port numbers?

Comment: if you try to use "/" instead of /mnt/efs/Fastq/ does it works?.

Comment: validate if the EFS has an File system policy in if this allows your role to mount the efs

Comment: I got this error: Essential container in task exited which makes sense because I didn't know where to specify the /mnt/efs/Fastq bit.  Though, different error is good right?

Comment: please update your answer with all the new configurations you have and the full logs.

Comment: just updated now.

Comment: The error is that "/mnt/efs/Fastq" does not exist (at least for the job), how do you create this path?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254668/discussion-between-clay-and-o-rka).